# "Visual Hashing Algorithm" for human viewing/checking? (Not visual hash, but algorithm)

Tags: user-interface, hash

So I'm building a rock paper scissors bot, and I need people to be able to be sure that the robot doesn't "cheat" and make its selection after the player chooses their throw.

Normally, for computer viewing, this is done by hashing the choice and maybe providing a salt, and then revealing the choice+salt.  But I want something that can be "instantly" verifiable by a human.  If I just hash the choice, people would cry foul on rigging the hash.

So my idea is to have a "visual hashing algorithm" of sorts -- a hashing algorithm that humans can perform themselves trivially and easily, and verify.

What my idea is right now is to have three boxes: Rock, Paper, and Scissors, and then have three other unlabeled boxes A, B, and C across from the RPS boxes.  Then I connect Rock to one of them using tangled lines, Paper to another, and C to another.  The lines are tangled so that it would take time to "follow back" the line from box B to, say, Scissors.

When the computer picks its throw, it "highlights" the corresponding box to the throw -- that is, if Scissors' tangled lines lead to Box B, it'll highlight Box B.  But it won't reveal that it was Scissors.  The human then is given, say, 3 seconds, to pick a throw.  3 seconds, hopefully, is not fast enough for them to detangle the lines and trace back from box B to Scissors.

Then, when the human picks the throw, the computer reveals Scissors, and also highlights the tangled line from Scissors to Box B so that it is clear that Scissors has lead to Box B this entire time, and it couldn't have just cheated.

While this would work, I think...it's a little ugly, and inelegant.  The human can easily verify that the computer didn't cheat, but at the same time, it seems unusual or weird and introduces so many UI elements that the screen might seem cluttered or untrustworthy.  The less UI elements/graphical footprint, the better.

Are there any solutions right now that exist that solve this issue?

1. The "hash" of the throw is presented, as well as the hashing algorithm, which takes time (at least 3 seconds) to "undo".
2. When the throw is revealed, it should be easily and visually and immediately identifiable that the hashing algorithm was performed validly and that the throw does indeed correspond to the hash
3. It uses as few UI elements as possible and has as small a graphical footprint as possible

Answer (score 2):

This is interesting. An idea in my head would be to display a 10x10 grid (of say 5 pixels per square) with a key;

**Red**: Rock; **Blue**: Scissors; **Green**: Paper

And fill the grid randomly with 33 red, 33 blue and 33 green, and then 1 random of the 3 colours. A human would struggle to identify the 34 colours over the other 2 in a small time period, but the count could be revealed on user input, along with optionally expanding the grid/highlighting the cells etc.

A small UI footprint, and neater than your solution, but whether it's good enough...

Comment: I think maybe counting 33 squares is too much effort to verify on the user's part, I'm looking for something that is instantly (within seconds) verifiable :(  Thank you for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 seconds, which calculation is correct?

```
R: 317 * 27 = 8829
P: 297 * 16 = 5605
S: 239 * 38 = 9082
```

When I tell you my answer, you could quickly verify with a calculator.